# I have a trouble with Distributivity proof

Tags: logic

I'm doing a programming logic activity but i'm having trouble proving this:
ϕ ∨ (ψ ∧ χ) ≡ (ϕ ∨ ψ) ∧ (ϕ ∨ χ)
Can Someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: *How* do you need to prove it? Using a truth-table? Algebra? Formal proof? Some other method?

Answer (score 1):

Its tedious but I would use a "truth table".
With three "variables" there $2^3 = 8$ possible combinations for $\psi$, $\phi$, and $\chi$-
TTT.  $T ^ T= T$ and $T v T= T$ on the left. On the right, $(T v T)^(T v T)= T ^ T= T$.

TTF.  $T ^ F= T v F= T$ on the left. On the right, $T v T= T$, $T v F= T$ and $T^T= T$.

You do the other 6, TFT, TFF, FTT, FTF, FFT, and FFF.
ϕ ∨ (ψ ∧ χ) ≡ (ϕ ∨ ψ) ∧ (ϕ ∨ χ)